# OCMock how to test library SEL parameter - OS X TDD

Tags: ios, unit-testing, cocoa, tdd, ocmock

I wonder how one can / should test a 'onFinished' selector, passed in as a parameter to a library class.

In particular I am using Google Toolbox for Mac OAuth library (gtm-oauth). There's a method in `GTMOAuthWindowController.m` with signature

`- (void)signInSheetModalForWindow:(NSWindow *)parentWindowOrNil                     delegate:(id)delegate finishedSelector:(SEL)finishedSelector`

That class is responsible for instantiating a login window, and when the login phase is finished the `(SEL) finishedSelector` is invoked.

How do I test my custom `(SEL)finishedSelector` or run it, so that I can verify it's behaviour? Because the implementation will call certain delegate methods and I'd like to verify that delegate methods are called.

If I set the SEL finishedSelector to be part of my class' header file, i.e visible for clients, I'll be exposing implementation details.

What is the best approach?

## Update

FYI
The SEL has the following signature, 
`- (void)windowController:(GTMOAuthWindowController *)windowController finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuthAuthentication *)auth error:(NSError *)error`

which further prevents me from exposing the method due to those GTM classes (!)

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Why don't you just call the finished selector, ie. `windowController:finishedWithAuth:error:` directly from your unit test? Your not testing `GTMOAuthWindowController` so you can assume that that works and will call the selector correctly. You want to test the implementation of `windowController:finishedWithAuth:error:`, right?

Comment: @ErikDoernenburg Yes, and there's the problem I think, in that case I would expose the details in my .h file. Right?

Comment: You mean you need to put `windowController:finishedWithAuth:error:` into the `.h` file of your class that implements that method? Does gtm-oauth maybe declare a protocol that you could adopt? Or, just make sure that the test class sees the declaration from the gtm-oauth lib and use the `id` type.

Comment: @ErikDoernenburg exactly what I mean. I didn't find such a protocol or method though.

Comment: If I'm following this correctly -- I just usually add a category in my test implementation that exposes methods not available in headers. Not relevant, but it would have been nice for Google to use a well defined block instead of a SEL.

Comment: @Ben Flynn There is a block variant of the method too. What do you suggest ?

Comment: Hmm, although a block feels more natural to me for the overall situation, I suppose it does present a similar issue when unit testing. I guess I might use an "andDo" block to capture the block argument to the method (via the invocation), then make assertions on it. It does feel a bit deeply nested to me, but at least you would have access to what you are trying to test.

Comment: I made the signature of the method visible in the test file. That is sufficient for now.